# object1 pushing object2 in x axis, but in y axis has no effect

Tags: android, libgdx

I have object1 (texture) and its moving under my finger how I wanted.
But I don't know how to set up condition for object2 (texture) to have pushing effect. Size of Object1: 128x64, Object2: 128x128.
That what I have so far works good in x axis. In y axis has no effect.

```
if(gameObject1.overlaps(gameObject2)){
        if(gameObject1.x<gameObject2.x&&gameObject1.y<gameObject2.y+128&&gameObject1.y>gameObject2.y-64){
            gameObject2.x+=16;
        }else
        if(gameObject1.x>gameObject2.x&&gameObject1.y<gameObject2.y+128&&gameObject1.y>gameObject2.y-64){
            gameObject2.x-=16;
        }

        if(gameObject1.y<gameObject2.y&&gameObject1.x>=gameObject2.x&&gameObject1.x+128<=gameObject2.x){
            gameObject2.y+=16;
        }else
        if(gameObject1.y>gameObject2.y&&gameObject1.x>=gameObject2.x&&gameObject1.x+128<=gameObject2.x){
            gameObject2.y-=16;}
```

In statement of y axis I removed some x condition:

```
    if(gameObject1.y<gameObject2.y)
{ gameObject2.y+=16; }
else 
if(gameObject1.y>gameObject2.y)
{ gameObject2.y-=16;}
```

now is moving diagonally up end down, but not street in x&y axis

Answer (score 0):

In your statements for y axis effect you have to identical conditions:

```
gameObject1.x>=gameObject2.x
gameObject1.x+128<=gameObject2.x
```

if one of your conditions is false then you'll have never any effect to its y position, so maybe check this. I didn't try to understand your logic, maybe problem is in your logical conditions.